# How to write to address (0X0D and 0X0E) with libusb 1.0.0

Tags: libusb

I have the need to write to a specific address (`0X0D` and `0X0E`) and I am using libusb-1.0.0.

I am able to read from that address, but I am unable to write something to that address, even though the documentation tells me that this is possible.

How do I write two bytes to a specific address?

Comment: Could you give an minimal example code that shows what is supposed to happen and what actually happens?